# Button com dois value só com html é possivel?

Tags: html, button, value

Quer colocar duas ações no campo value de um button, utilizando apenas html. É possivel?

Meu button original:

```
<button type='roll' name='roll_arma1' value='&{template:default} {{name=Ataque @{nomearma1} @{arma1}}} {{Sucessos=[[{5d4}>3+@{arma1}]]}}'>
```

eu queria inserir dentro do value a ação #macro1, que executa uma função dentro do site que utilizo, roll20.net

ou ainda transformar este dois botões abaixo em um único:

```
<button type='roll' name='roll_arma1' value='&{template:default} {{name=Ataque @{nomearma1} @{arma1}}} {{Sucessos=[[{5d4}>3+@{arma1}]]}}'></button>

<button type='roll' name='roll_arma1' value='!ammo @{selected|character_id} municao1 -1'></button>
```

Comment: Não consegui compreender sua dúvida, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer. Por favor, edite a pergunta e descreva melhor o problema. Busque, também, fazer um [mcve] e aproveite para fazer o [tour].

Comment: Vocês diz 2 VALORES ou 2 AÇÕES como Submit, Click?

Comment: Meu button original:

<button type='roll' name='roll_arma1' value='&{template:default} {{name=Ataque @{nomearma1} @{arma1}}} {{Sucessos=[[{5d4}>3+@{arma1}]]}}'>

eu queria inserir dentro do value a ação #macro1, que executa uma função dentro do site que utilizo, roll20.net

Comment: Daniel essa informação que você disponibilizou nos comentários é essencial na pergunta, fique a vontade para edita-la se quiser.

Comment: @DanielReis você esta usando angular?
Descreva melhor o cenário.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar suas próprias propriedades para suas tags html usando a palavra `data-`:

```
<button type='roll' id='roll_arma1' data-valor-um='meu valor 1' data-valor-dois='meu segundo valor'></button>
```

Para acessá-los, use:

```
    function pegaValores(){
      var valor1= $("#roll_arma1").data('valor-um');
      var valor2= $("#roll_arma1").data('valor-dois');
      console.log(exigeIdade);
    });
```

Então, chame a função no evento onclick do seu botão. Adapte de acordo com sua necessidade.

Comment: Deu certo ou precisa de algo mais?